# Using sed for brackets

Tags: text-processing, sed

I would like to find out, if, in my file, there is a right number of brackets.
I can make my file look like

`(((()))()(()))
((()))()`

How can I use `sed` to compute those brackets and print yes or no instead of the line, if the number of brackets is right or not?

Comment: Just to be clear... the brackets do not extend *beyond* the line?

Comment: Yes, each line should have its own brackets right, no brackets over the line should be counted for this line.

Comment: Can there be other characters inside the brackets?

Comment: I managed to clear any other characters so on the line, there are only "(" and ")".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just for test purpose

```
sed ':1;s/([^()]*)//g;t1;s/.*[()].*/No/;t;s/.*/Yes/'
```

prints "Yes" for correct number and "No" for opposite for each line.

Answer (score 3):

```
sed '  s/.*/YES(&)/;:t
       s/([^()]*)//g;tt
       s/.....*/NO/'
```

Answer (score 2):

Simple Perl solution:

```
perl -ne '1 while s/\(\)//g; print /[()]/ ? "Invalid\n" : "OK\n"' input.txt
```

Explanation: the while loop removes `()` until it's no longer possible. If there are any parentheses left, they were not balanced.

Answer (score 0):

The following is doing a more complex job: **marking the first un-matched parentheses**:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
undef $/;
$_= <>;                   # slurp input
my $P = qr{[^()]*};       # $P = not parentheses

                          # repace matched parentheses by marks
while(s!       \( ($P) \)        !\cA$1\cB!gx){}
while(s!^ ($P) \( (.*) \) ($P) $ !$1\cB$2\cB$3!sgx){}

s!([()])! → $1!;          # mark the first unmatched ()
y!\cA\cB!()!;             # replace marks

print
```

Usage:

```
$ cat f
1(2(3(4(5)6)7)8(9)10(
   11(12)13)14)  (15 ( and ) 
      (16(17(18)19)
   20)21(22)23
$ parentesis f
1(2(3(4(5)6)7)8(9)10(
   11(12)13)14)   → (15 ( and ) 
      (16(17(18)19)
   20)21(22)23
```